# Unique id for column that resets value

Tags: pandas

I have to create an id in a pandas df where a counter resets itself.
My data looks like

```
counter
0
0
1
1
1
2
0
1
1
```

My desired output looks like

```
counter id
0        0
0        0
1        1
1        1
1        1
2        2
0        3
1        4
1        4
```

I have tried the following, which does not help. Any help will be appreciated.

```
df['id'] = df.groupby(df.counter.tolist(), sort=False).ngroup()
```

Comment: @Brendan your answer is fine and works in more general cases where the column isn't numeric.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Check `diff` and `cumsum`

```
df['id'] = df.diff().ne(0).cumsum()-1
```

Another way of using `itertools.groupby`

```
from itertools import groupby
sum([ [y]*len(list(g)) for y,(_,g) in enumerate(groupby(df.counter))],[])
Out[46]: [0, 0, 1, 1, 1, 2, 3, 4, 4]
```